# ExtJS 4 > Grid Editor > Editor with "datefield" xtype doesn't fill properly

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

When I double-click a record for editing, it doesn't fill the date picker (i.e. the date picker shows blank, even though the record has the value).

[image]

I have searched a lot, but didn't get any fix.

Anyone has any idea...?

Comment: Please provide your grid column declaration code, a screen shot is useful but not enough to determine the problem.

Comment: :) VOTE UP this QUESTION (if you find it useful).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't tell if you have this already... but you need to make sure that the column editor is configured properly, for example:

```
columns: [{
    // column 1 - NAME
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'the_name',
    flex: 1
}, {
    // column 2 - DATE
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    header: 'Date',
    dataIndex: 'the_date',
    width: 90,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        allowBlank: true,
        format: 'm/d/Y',
    }
}, {
    // column 3...
}],
//other grid configs...
```

Comment: can you have a look at this Please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920402/retain-the-already-present-value-of-the-cell-for-edit-on-click

Answer (score 1):

Probably your 'the_date' field is not configured as 'date' in the model/store configuration.