# Retain the already present value of the cell for edit on click

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, extjs4

I've a grid cloumn with xtype:datecolumn as below,
Now what happens is when i want to alter the value of the cell , i.e change the time on click the cell becomes blank for editing and on clicking way the previous value comes back, I want the value to be present to edit on click

this is my **gridcolumn**

```
{
   text: ' Time',
   dataIndex: 'time',
   xtype: 'datecolumn',
   format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
   editor: {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            allowBlank: false,
            maskRe: /[0-9,:,-]/
           }
  },
```

[image: small screen shot][image]
How will I be achieve this?
[image]
**To edit the same old value rather than going blank and choosing the new date**
Thanks

Comment: Anyone here to help me??

Comment: Give some more information. 1:) Are you using buffered Store, 2:) Give the code on edit click event.

Comment: i'm not using any onClick event, Simple gridColumn with editor, since datecolumn xtype, we donot require any store it opens a inbuilt calender, Correct

Comment: No that is fine. I agree you need to store. I just ask for grid are you using buffered store or what.

Comment: Also can you create a fiddle. Easy to understand problem.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r3p here I tried , it works actually but the same thing it doesn't work in a application, everything is same and Equal, So thought i could add some event or listeners??

Comment: Here also when you select other value and click out side column and again click for edit you can see the previous selected value is also heiglighted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138622/discussion-between-udid-and-john-humanyun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the format issue, I fixed it.. 
I was getting the data from the db with the format `m/d/Y H:m:s` and the the format in the grid was `Y-m-d H:m:s`  changing the format in the backend fixed the issue.

Thanks @UDID for pointing me to debugging.